# Filter datatable with Linq by a decimal list in c#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, contains

I have got a datatable and I want to filter by a value. This is working:

```
 var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<decimal?>("decimal_col") == 1);
```

Now I want to filter by a list of decimals. I have tried to put `contains` but it is not working. This is the list:

```
var list = new List<decimal>() { 8, 3, 2, 1 };
```

And this is what I want, but it is not working:

```
var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => r.Field<decimal?>("decimal_col").Contains(list));
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use list.Contains(). The syntax is `List<T>.Contains(item)` (Note the difference, In the query in OP, it was in correctly given as item.Contains(list))

```
var result = datatable.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => list.Contains(r.Field<decimal?>("decimal_col")));
```

You can read more on the syntax of List.Contains [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if the *value* "contains" the *list*.  It's the other way around.  The *list* would "contain" the *value*:

```
list.Contains(r.Field<decimal?>("decimal_col"))
```